# Controller is not a function, got undefined in jasmine testing with angular(route - $stateProvider)

Tags: angularjs, karma-jasmine, angle

i am using angle theme with Angular for my project and i am doing unit testing on this using jasmine framework. But when i run the test cases, it gives error of "Argument 'controller' is not a function, got undefined". here is my test.js file....

```
describe('registrationController',function(){
beforeEach(module('appTesting'));
var $controller;
beforeEach(inject(function(_$controller_){
    $controller = _$controller_;
}));
it('Check Working Or Not', function() {
    var $scope = {};
    var controller = $controller('registrationController', { $scope: $scope });
    $scope.password = 'passwordlength';
    $scope.grade();
    expect($scope.strength).toEqual('strong');
});
```

});

Error -

```
Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'registrationController' is not a function, got undefined http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.10/ng/areq?p0=registrationController&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined
```

No i am using karma to run jasmine.

I am defining my module here

```
var App = angular.module('appTesting', ['ngRoute', 'ngAnimate', 'ngStorage', 'ngCookies', 'pascalprecht.translate', 'ui.bootstrap', 'ui.router', 'oc.lazyLoad', 'cfp.loadingBar', 'ngSanitize', 'ngResource'])
      .run(["$rootScope", "$state", "$stateParams",  '$window', '$templateCache', function ($rootScope, $state, $stateParams, $window, $templateCache, $location) {
          // Set reference to access them from any scope
          $rootScope.$state = $state;
          $rootScope.$stateParams = $stateParams;
          $rootScope.$storage = $window.localStorage;
        }
      ]);

App.config(['$stateProvider','$urlRouterProvider', '$controllerProvider', '$compileProvider', '$filterProvider', '$provide', '$ocLazyLoadProvider', 'APP_REQUIRES', 'RouteHelpersProvider',
function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $controllerProvider, $compileProvider, $filterProvider, $provide, $ocLazyLoadProvider, appRequires, helper) {


 'use strict';
App.controller = $controllerProvider.register;
App.directive  = $compileProvider.directive;
 App.filter     = $filterProvider.register;


App.factory    = $provide.factory;

App.service    = $provide.service;
App.constant   = $provide.constant;
 App.value      = $provide.value;
 $stateProvider
.state('app.registrationState', {
    url: '/registration',
    title: 'Ragistration Page',
    templateUrl: helper.basepath('registrationPage.html'),
    resolve: helper.resolveFor('registrationController','angularFileUpload')
})
}])
.controller('NullController', function() {});
App.constant('APP_REQUIRES', { 
scripts: 
{
  'registrationController' :['app/js/registrationcontroller.js'],
}
});
```

Comment: please add more code to find idea...

Answer (score 1):

## Angular

Can the controller be found?

- Do you have a controller named `registrationController`?
- Is it in a module named `appTesting`?

You should have the following code somewhere in your app:

```
angular.module("appTesting").controller("registrationController", ...);
```

## Karma

If you are using Karma-jasmine:

- Did you include the file where you define the controller (`registration-controller.js`) in your `karma.conf.js`?

*karma.conf.js*

```
module.exports = function(config) {config.set({
  files : [
    'src/registration-controller.js',
    ...
    ],
  ...
});};
```

## Jasmine

If you're not using Karma to run Jasmine, I'm assuming you're using the Jasmine test runner (HTML file). In that case:

- Did you include the controller in the HTML file?

You need to include the controller's script:

```
<head>
  ...
  <script type="text/javascript" src="src/registration-controller.js"></script>
  ...
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

Either the controller cannot be found or was not created due to error on the source code where controller was defined.

In my case, it was due to a statement that had error which affected succeeding lines of code cause the controller to be not loaded.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen due to variety of reasons.

-> controller name is not referenced right
-> controller is not created due to some error.

In my case, I had the controller name mismatched in

```
directive:
.controller('IAddController', AddController)

Jasmine spec.ts:
// Instantiate controller
        addController= $controller<any>('AddController', {*
```